# Process dimension task is querying the wrong column!

Tags: data-warehouse, ssas, dimension

I'm in the process of building a new data warehouse and I am starting out by building a few dimensions.  I have created a fairly typical "Date" dimension and that seems ok.  Now I am trying to create a "Person" dimension which contains "Date of Birth Key" and "Date of Death Key" attributes, both of which are related to the key attribute of the Date dimension.

When I process the Person dimension I am receiving an error about duplicate keys.  Looking into it, I found that the code that is generated for processing the Date of Birth attribute is incorrectly joining to the Date dimension using the Date of Death column:

```
SELECT   DISTINCT
         [Dim_Person].[Date of birth key]
         ,[Dim_Date].[FullDate]
FROM     [Dim].[Person] AS [Dim_Person],
         [Dim].[Date] AS [Dim_Date]
WHERE 
   [Dim_Person].[Date of death key] = [Dim_Date].[DateKey]  <--- This line is WRONG!
```

I have attached a screenshot showing the Date of Birth attribute.  The Date of Death attribute is identical other than looking at the Date of Death Key field.

[image: Date of Birth attribute]

Am I doing something wrong, or is this a bug in SSAS ?